# Issue related to fragment orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having a main activity and two fragments. By default the first fragment appears on the activity (Let's call this fragment 'A'). On a button click I am adding second fragment to the activity (Let's call this fragment 'B'). I have set the screen orientation of the activity as portrait in manifest.

Issue I am facing is that when I call the camera from fragment B and I take an image in landscape mode and clicks on the tick icon in camera intent, my application is coming back to fragment A instead of fragment B.

It will be helpful if anyone can suggest me a solution for this issue.

Comment: When you change your orientation, your activity will restarted so that's your fragment A is coming back. for that you have to store your fragment state.

Answer (score 1):

In your onActivityResult() method, you may want to set which fragment you want to load after taking a picture.